# How to list all columns an PK name for relevant columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, outer-join

I want to display all columns of a table and the Primary Key name for a column, if that column belongs to the PK.
So, expected final result will be a 2 column output, the first being the column_name and the second being constraint_name, where constraint_type='P'. For those columns that are not part of the PK, the second column in the display resultset will be NULL and for those columns that are part of the PK, the second column in the resultset will show the PK name.
I am trying a combination of OUTER JOIN involving DBA_TAB_COLS, DBA_CONSTRAINTS, DBA_CONS_COLUMNS, but not getting the desired result.
I am looking for all columns to be listed and not just PK columns.

Comment: Please provide the code you currently have. Should be `*_tab_cols left join *_cons_columns left join *_constraints` and constraint type in the join conditions

Comment: @astentx Here's the query ... The PK name (in output column #2) displayed for all rows, instead of only for the ones defining it

SELECT DISTINCT T1.column_name, T2.constraint_name
FROM 
     DBA_TAB_COLS           T1
    ,DBA_CONSTRAINTS        T2
    ,DBA_CONS_COLUMNS       T3
WHERE 1=1 
  AND T1.owner = ?
  AND T2.constraint_type = 'P'
  AND T1.hidden_column = 'NO'
  AND T1.owner = T2.owner 
  AND T2.owner = T3.owner 
  AND T1.table_name = T2.table_name
  AND T2.table_name = T3.table_name(+)
  AND T2.constraint_name = T3.constraint_name(+)
  AND T1.table_name IN (?)
;

Answer (score 1):

First join the primary key constraint (**dba_constraints**) to the constraint columns (**dba_cons_columns**). Then, outer join that result to all columns in the table (**dba_tab_cols**).

```
SELECT dtc.column_name
      ,iv.constraint_name
  FROM dba_tab_cols dtc
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT dcc.owner
            ,dcc.table_name
            ,dcc.column_name
            ,dcc.constraint_name
        FROM dba_constraints dc
        JOIN dba_cons_columns dcc ON (dcc.owner = dc.owner
                                      AND dcc.constraint_name = dc.constraint_name)
       WHERE dc.constraint_type = 'P'
  ) iv ON (dtc.owner = iv.owner
            AND dtc.table_name = iv.table_name
            AND dtc.column_name = iv.column_name)
 WHERE dtc.hidden_column = 'NO'
   AND dtc.owner = ?
   AND dtc.table_name IN (?)
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. I see the error in my join order